# How to make elasticsearch works with the full given text?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have searchtext like "Document se". If i serach that in elasticserach it gives result according to "Document" and "se" words which i dont want. I want the result which consists of "Document se" text (case insensitive). I a trying it in spring boot project with elasticserach but dont know what to do.

Mapping:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "my": {
        "properties": {
          "active": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "label": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "refresh_interval": "1s",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "my_index",
        "creation_date": "1558871069777",
        "store": {
          "type": "fs"
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "X1b0YIgGSOu7vki2RjqjsA",
        "version": {
          "created": "6040399"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the mapping of you index and the field against which you indexed this value. Also add the query that you have tried.

Comment: {"my_index":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"my":{"properties":{"active":{"type":"boolean"},"id":{"type":"keyword"},"label":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"type":{"type":"keyword"}}}},"settings":{"index":{"refresh_interval":"1s","number_of_shards":"5","provided_name":"my_index","creation_date":"1558871069777","store":{"type":"fs"},"number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"X1b0YIgGSOu7vki2RjqjsA","version":{"created":"6040399"}}}}}

Comment: this is the mapping of my index

Comment: i want the search on the basis of "label" field

Comment: If I am not wrong, are you try to make a phrase query? in your example, documents consist of "documents se" must come and if document contains "documents have se" it shoud not come in search results?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal yes

Comment: @user , can you provide your search query?